# PHP - Variable blank when appended to string

Tags: php, html, string, variables, post

I am trying to send a variable in the URL so it can be accessed between pages. I can freely echo this variable to ensure that it is, in fact, not blank.

The issue arises when trying to append it to a variable `$link`. Then, it will not actually append anything.

What is even stranger to me is that if I do that very same operation of appending, but outside of its current if-statement, it will actually work. It appends nothing within the if-statement, it seems.

Here is the code for the issue.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo "Current user: $username <br>"; //Works. Outputs value as expected.

$link = 'view.php?username=' . $username; //This also works. The username is appended 
//successfully.
echo $link;

if(isset($_POST['viewbutton']))
{
    $link = 'view.php?username=' . $username; //Here, nothing is appended.
    header('location: '.$link);
}

/* Output page elements. */
$cmd = "./wpmlp options.wpml";
exec($cmd, $output, $status);
foreach($output as $line) echo $line;
```

Comment: that would suggest that `$_POST['viewbutton']` **isn't** set then... try a vardump on the `$_POST` array and see what's there

Comment: It is set. I know this because the link works... that is, I am redirected to "view.php?username=".

Comment: then something else must be sending you, because you can't send headers after you've output something to the page. If this was your actual code - the `header()` method wouldn't work anyway because it's placed after you've `echo`'d something out to the page.

Comment: You should be getting a `Headers already sent` warning about that.

Comment: I've edited the code to show an echo statement I have omitted in my example. It used to be before the if-statement but now it is after. Nothing has changed. The same error persists no matter where I place the exec and echo statement.

Comment: Also, the var_dump reveals that only the username is in fact present in $_POST.

Comment: It's not the username that you're testing in your if statement, it's the `viewbutton` index... and unless you've managed to defy the rules of the PHP programming language that `header` call still isn't doing anything in your code.

Comment: I am not testing the username in the if-statement. The purpose of the if-statement is to check if that particular button was pressed, if it was, then the username should be appended to the link. The username variable has a value before the if-statement, but becomes blank once inside.

Comment: @MacroMan that is completely false. A button with a `name` attribute, when clicked will be included in the POST body

Comment: That doesn't really explain how when I press the button I am redirected to `view.php?username=`, there are also elseif statements used for different buttons (wherein different buttons redirect to different URLs), and when pressed they also redirect to their appropriate URLs. Given that, I truly do not understand how the if-statement could have not been executed.

Comment: I know for a fact that the if-statement is actually being reached because its code executes. My only question is why the variable is cleared once the if-statement is reached,

Comment: @moosefoot is it possible that when the POST body **does** contain `viewbutton`, it **does not** contain a `username` property? I highly recommend attaching a debugger and stepping through your code, line-by-line. You can also check the POST request in your browser's *Network* console

Comment: @Phil that is entirely possible, and provides the basis for a reason as to _why_ the value is being cleared, unlike previous answers. I suppose that is possible, but as a beginner to PHP/HTML I have no idea why that could happen.

Comment: @moosefoot what does your `<form>` look like?

Comment: @Barmar OP could have output buffering enabled (via `php.ini`). I suspect if that is the case, it would be the sole reason for so much confusion (us and theirs)

Comment: @Phil yes of course, my comment was misleading (although I doubt that's the case here)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_POST['viewbutton']))
{
    echo('viewbutton index not set inside POST array!'):
}
elseif(empty($_POST['viewbutton']))
{
    echo('viewbutton is set, but empty');
}
else
{
    header('location: view.php?username=' . $_POST['username']);
}
```

1. your `viewbutton` index obviously isn't set inside your `$_POST` array
2. You can't send headers after you've outputted something to the page